# How is a resource instance populated with keys in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've used the scaffold generator to create CRUD orientated around an 'automatic' resource. The manual resources only contains a 'name' column, a string, and, of course, an 'id' column, an integer.

I also created, by hand, CRUD oriented around a 'manual' resource. The manual resource is of an identical schema to the automatic resource. I created logical routes for my manually created controller actions.

What I cannot understand is how a new resource instance is populated with the keys pertaining to the resource column names.

Here is the scaffold-generated action necessary to create a new row in the automatic resource:

```
  def new
    @automatic = Automatic.new
  end
```

In *views/automatic/new* I created an erb tag to observe the resource instance:

```
<%= debug @automatic %>
```

Here's what it printed to the screen:

```
--- !ruby/object:Automatic
attributes:
  id: 
  name:
```

As I suspected.

Here is the manually created action necessary to create a new row in manual resource:

```
 def new
    @manual= Manual.new
 end
```

In *views/manual/new* I created an erb tag to observe the resource instance:

```
<%= debug @manual %>
```

Here's what it printed to the screen:

```
--- 
...
```

Completely empty! Attempting to update the name column results in a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in FeaturesController#create` error? The Models are identical, and the answer must lie in the fact the keys aren't populated into my manual resource instance.

Why not? I don't understand. Their MVC paths are identical.

This works perfectly:

```
@automatic = Automatic.new
```

And this doesn't really work at all:

```
@manual = Manual.new
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this. I had to turn the rails server off and on again. The interpreter must save the resource column names somewhere whenever the server boots up, and uses these when creating new instances.

Here's a good link than expounds on this concept:
[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)

In all seriousness, there's also a HUGE gotcha with rails 4.0. You now need to whitelist all of your new dynamic resource methods in your controller. Here:

```
   def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:title, :artist, :release_date, :genre)
   end
```

Say you properly created a new column called artist_id in here, and implemented the necessary CRUD! It would still not be created in Rails 4. You need to explictly add it to the **.permit** method above as a symbol **:artist_id**

Bit annoying, but I'm sure it's for our own good :)

Comment: Saying that, I don't like how we need to specify permitted entries in my controllers. I want to do it once, in my model. Keep it all organised and DRY.